# showSoftwareKeyboard unsets fullscreen and alters the layout

Tags: android, qt, qml, qt-necessitas

When I click a TextInput field, the software keyboard shows up, but it seems like it tries to compress the entire layout in the remaining space above the keyboard. All elements with relative size ends up smaller. Are there any general guidelines for solving this problem?

Answer (score 0):

To fix it you should use **LinearLayout**. Because Relative depends of other elements.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" in the AndroidManifest.xml file, inside the application tag.

Comment: I cant find the manifest file in the project folder, nor in Qt Creator (necessitas). It is a Qt Quick application.